# Use nmap or .NET to find Microsoft SQL servers without requiring authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server, network-programming

I need to scan and locate **SQL Server instances** on my local LAN based on Ip address list or range and I am looking for the following information:

1. **port** on which sql server is listening (regular is **1433/1434** but can be changed),
2. **ip address** of the machine,
3. **hostname** of the machine where sql server is running,
4. instance version like **10.5.2500.0**
5. instance name information e.g **Joe\SQLExpress**

I will not have access to any credentials either windows or sql servers. The bets bet is usng windows authentication but i would prefer a discovery-based approach. Also i don't want to raise false alarms during the scan and the scan has to be non-intrusive. The scan has to perform several vulnerability tests(later on) which will involve inspection and further information and should therefore not require any access credentials for each server.

Moreover, some of the instances may have **SQL Server Browser service** disabled or may have **SQL Server agent service** stopped.

I need to be able to query all of the SQL Server instances for a given range of IP addresses. I have been trying to use arguments here:

1. [here](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ms-sql-info.html)

and

1. [here](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ms-sql-config.html)

A C# based solution can also help as long as it returns all instances irrespective of whether SQL Server Browser, or SQL Server agent is running or not.

But I want my scan to be as much non-intrusive as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by non-intrusive.  Not having credentials to connect has nothing to do with looking for whether a server exists.

Comment: By non-intrusive means that the script/solution should not be involving credentials as this will be kind of a potential security risk. Also, i need some means of discovery mechanism to determine the kind of sql server, version, instance name and ip address that should not involve any kind of authentication to get the required details as mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Did you check SQLPing? http://www.sqlsecurity.com/downloads

Comment: Yes. But SQlPing 3.0 is limited in a sense that in stealth mode it does not return instance or port information. Also, officially 2008 R2 is not supported in it. I have looked at .cs code too provided at their site, but was not helpful. We have SQL Server 2008 R2 or later server instances on our corporate network

Comment: Do you mean you don't have credentials for connecting to SQL Server, or to Windows? Or to both? Considering just the version information, you [don't absolutely need](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) to log on to SQL Server to get it, but you at least need to be able to log on to Windows with appropriate credentials.

Comment: I need to scan my local network and retrieve list of sql servers. I also require information such as IP address of sql server, instance name like Joe\SQlExpress, port (in case it is different from 1433/1434), and hostname of the machine e.g. Joe. I already know this information public and there are multiple ways of querying it PING, Telnet, WMI etc..I wonder why i would need credentials of like 100s of servers if i have to do a vulnerability test. Besides, whats the point of requiring credentials to get information which should be otherwise publicly accessible.

Comment: I'm slightly confused about whether you're trying to do a software inventory or a penetration test. Surely the point of a vulnerability test is to see what you can achieve without credentials? A lot of information shouldn't be publicly accessible, because it's a potential information disclosure vulnerability. For example, if you can determine that a host is running an old, unpatched version of a certain application then you may be able to use a known attack to compromise it. So requiring authentication in order to gather detailed information about a system is generally a good thing.

Comment: If you please go through my question again, you would know that, at this point in time, the task at hand , is to only gather the above information which is supposed to be publicly accessible. In my scenario i will not have access to any kind of credentials ( there are going to hundreds of servers which need to be scanned for this information on a local network).

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2005 and beyond there is a documented and supported way, using WMI, see [FAQ: Detecting SQL Server 2005 using WMI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/07/29/682254.aspx). This will detect any installed instance, irrelevant of the fact that is running or not, and w/o opening any connection to the SQL Server itself. Of course it requires appropriate permissions to query the remote *machine* WMI.

For SQL 2000 the only way is to use unsupported registry hacks (look for specific keys).